# Advanced Describe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

Is there a more advanced function like the describe that the pandas has?
Normally i will go on like :

```
r = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000), columns = ['A'])
r.describe()
```

and i will get a nice summary.Like this one:

```
                A
count  1000.000000
mean      0.010230
std       0.982562
min      -2.775969
25%      -0.664840
50%       0.015452
75%       0.694440
max       3.101434
```

Can i find something a little more elaborate in statsmodels or scipy maybe?

Comment: what is more 'advanced' mean?

Comment: I second Jeff's comment. This questing currently too vague to answer.

Comment: "Advance"? Meaning skewness, kurtosis, entropy...?

Comment: you can certainly make one!

Comment: I was looking for something similar to a describe on statsmodels with sums, modes, skewness, kurtosis and maybe more. Any ideas? I think i have seen something similar on statsmodels.

Comment: There was a Describe function or class under development in statsmodels, but nobody has looked at it in a long time, since pandas is covering almost all of this area now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
from scipy.stats import describe
describe(r, axis=0)
```

It will give you the size, (min,max), mean, variance, skewness, and kurtosis

Answer (score 9):

I'd rather bound to leverage the pandas library (add [variance](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.var.html), [skewness](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.skew.html), [kurtosis](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.kurtosis.html)) than use 'external' ones, say:

```
    stats = df.describe()
    stats.loc['var'] = df.var().tolist()
    stats.loc['skew'] = df.skew().tolist()
    stats.loc['kurt'] = df.kurtosis().tolist()
    print(stats)
```

PD: pandas_profiling is amazing though

Yerart

Answer (score 8):

```
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport
eda = ProfileReport(df)
display(eda)
```

[Pandas profiling](https://ydata-profiling.ydata.ai/docs/master/index.html) is a very powerful tool which gives you almost complete EDA of your dataset starting from missing values, correlations, heat-maps and what not!

Comment: One warning when i used it in jupyter notebook it caused problem with ploting because it resets something in the display mode etc.  To reset I used 


%matplotlib inline

and it went back to normal

Answer (score 1):

Found this excellent solution after much searching. It is simple and extends the existing describe() method.  It adds two rows to the describe() method output, one for kurtosis and one for skew, by creating a new function describex().

Custom function to add skewness and kurtosis in descriptive stats to a pandas dataframe:

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    def describex(data):
        data = pd.DataFrame(data)
        stats = data.describe()
        skewness = data.skew()
        kurtosis = data.kurtosis()
        skewness_df = pd.DataFrame({'skewness':skewness}).T
        kurtosis_df = pd.DataFrame({'kurtosis':kurtosis}).T
        return stats.append([kurtosis_df,skewness_df])
```

It is similar to the previous answer, but creates a callable function.

[source: https://gist.github.com/chkoar/5cb11b22b6733cbd408912b518e43a94](https://gist.github.com/chkoar/5cb11b22b6733cbd408912b518e43a94)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**:  ".append" method has been deprecated in Pandas.  To use the same function with as little disruption as possible the "._append" method should be used.

**HERE IS THE UPDATED CODE**:

```
import pandas as pd

def describex(data):
    data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    stats = data.describe()
    skewness = data.skew()
    kurtosis = data.kurtosis()
    skewness_df = pd.DataFrame({'skewness':skewness}).T
    kurtosis_df = pd.DataFrame({'kurtosis':kurtosis}).T
    return stats._append([kurtosis_df,skewness_df])
```

EVERYTHING IS THE SAME EXCEPT FOR THE UNDERSCORE "_" PRECEDING THE "append" KEYWORD: "._append".

".append" vs "._append"

REFERENCE:  [DataFrame object has no attribute append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75956209/dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-append/76725269#76725269)

Comment: No, `_append` is a **private** method. It could be removed from pandas API or its behavior altered without any warning. `append` was removed for a good reason, don't recommend to use a function that could be worse...

Comment: Can you recommend a means by which to preserve or replicate the "describex" function without using the ".append" or "._append" methods?