# Extended Describe Pandas and beyond

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I am new to python and pandas. My question is related to that question:
[Advanced Describe Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959207/advanced-describe-pandas)

Is it possible to add some functions to reply by noobie like:
geometric mean, weighted mean, harmonic mean, geometric standard deviation, etc.

```
import pandas as pd
    
    def describex(data):
        data = pd.DataFrame(data)
        stats = data.describe()
        skewness = data.skew()
        kurtosis = data.kurtosis()
        skewness_df = pd.DataFrame({'skewness':skewness}).T
        kurtosis_df = pd.DataFrame({'kurtosis':kurtosis}).T
        return stats.append([kurtosis_df,skewness_df])
```

So basically I am  interested in adding something for example from scipy.stats that is not as these functions above originated from pandas. I want to have much more informations from descriptive statistics than standard describe offers. What I tried so far was adding more functions from pandas, and with that I am OK, but wasn't able to attach more functions that are outside of pandas.
How do I do it, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you could do.

One suggestion is to use the [pandas-profiling](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-profiling/) library, which can generate a comprehensive report on the data including basic statistics, correlation analysis, data type analysis, missing values analysis, and more. This can be a very useful tool for quickly getting a comprehensive overview of the dataset.

Another suggestion is to use the [scipy.stats](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) library to add any advanced statistics to your custom function. The scipy.stats library probably has a function to compute any statistic you're looking for.

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gmean

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

def describex(data):
    data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    stats = data.describe()
    skewness = data.skew()
    kurtosis = data.kurtosis()
    skewness_df = pd.DataFrame({'skewness':skewness}).T
    kurtosis_df = pd.DataFrame({'kurtosis':kurtosis}).T
    gmean_df = pd.DataFrame(df.apply(gmean, axis=0),columns=['gmean']).T
    return stats.append([kurtosis_df,skewness_df,gmean_df])

print(describex(df))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you @g.newt, but as per your suggestion:"to use the scipy.stats library to add any advanced statistics to your custom function." - can you show me with code how to do it ? Maybe by adding geometric mean as an example.

Comment: Sure. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I updated my answer. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, it is, thank you, 
I received that warning:"FutureWarning: The 'mad' method is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To compute the same result, you may do `(df - df.mean()).abs().mean()`.Because I added: mad_df = pd.DataFrame({'mad':mad}).T.
  mad = data.mad()". Where should I place it ?

Comment: That is just a warning, don't worry about it. Also, you should mark the solution correct if it answered your question.

Comment: Just asking as new here:
1. Is it ok to ask additional questions regarding that topic when solution was already accepted here ? 
2. Is it ok to present what I have done extending that solution code ? That would have been done as an my new Answer to the question as in comments characacters are limited, but still, is it ok here ?